# No Javascript Fallback for AJAX Form submission

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to AJAX and am in the process of converting some regular HTML forms to AJAX.

My existing implementation is as follows - form (on page1.php) posts to page2.php which does some validation on post data and redirects to an error page if something is missing. If the input is fine, it includes page3.php which processes the request and redirects back to page1.php.

php/page1.php

```
<form method="post" action="/php/page2.php" >
   <input type="text" name="input1" placeholder="Howdy..." />
   <input type="text" name="input2" placeholder="Howdy..." />

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />      
</form>
```

php/page2.php

```
<?php

  // perform some validation on inputs
  if (empty($_POST['input1']))
  {
     $location ='Location: /php/error.php';
     header($location);
     exit;
  }

  // Inputs are fine
  include('/php/page3.php');

?>
```

page3.php

```
<?php

  // do some form processing


  // redirect back to page1.php
  $location = 'Location: /php/page1.php";
  header($location);
  exit;
?>
```

To convert to AJAX, I am using @SSL's solution on this SO link [How to show loading gif when request goes Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813830/how-to-show-loading-gif-when-request-goes-ajax)
http://jsfiddle.net/clickthelink/Uwcuz/1/

The error from validation and success page are both displayed back on page1.php via the callback function.

php/page2.php

```
<?php

  // perform some validation on inputs
  if (empty($_POST['input1']))
  {
     // Echo erorr code isntead of redirect
     echo "Please enter input1";
     return;

     //$location ='Location: /php/error.php';
     //header($location);
     //exit;
  }

  // Inputs are fine
  include('/php/page3.php');

?>
```

page3.php

```
<?php

  // do some form processing

  // Echo success instead of redirect
  echo "SUCCESS";

  // redirect back to page1.php
  //$location = 'Location: /php/page1.php";
  //header($location);
  //exit;
?>
```

This part is working fine.

My question (finally) is how do I handle users who have javascript disabled? I know the form will get submitted appropriately but I wont get the redirect back in case of the error or success. I would like to retain header() redirect type of functionality in this case also. Is this possible? I would appreciate the help.

Comment: You can easily recognize if a request is an AJAX call or not, cause it sets a HTTP header. So it should be possible to have your PHP backend respond differently in case of a form submission without js.

Comment: Not sure why this question is downvoted? Would appreciate if the person downvoting left a comment so I know what I'm doing wrong. By the way, I did find some questions on SO about AJAX fallback with no JS but nothing specific to re-direction back to the original page.

Comment: @gpgekko Thanks for your quick response. Are you suggesting the same thing as what quoo suggested? or something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your current form setup as-is, if it is working for you without javascript.

For javascript enabled browsers you can hijack the 'submit' event on the form. Capture the event and post the form, via ajax, to scripts/pages that handle and return the data in a javascript-friendly format for final consumption.

For example, using jquery:

```
<form method="post" action="/php/page2.php"  id="js-form" >
    <input type="text" name="input1" placeholder="Howdy..." />
    <input type="text" name="input2" placeholder="Howdy..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />      
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#js-form').on('submit',function(e){

        // logic to submit ajax form and handle response

        // return false to cancel native browser form submission.
        return false;
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Another idea is to keep the pages you already have, but send a flag with the ajax request to disable the browser redirect headers. For example, add 'src=ajax' when submitting the form via ajax. Then in the script use logic to say:

```
<?php
    if( !empty($_REQUEST['src'] && $_REQUEST['src'] == 'ajax' ) {
        // add redirect logic here.
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I really like your idea of adding a new flag to identify ajax submissions. Can you please clarify how to do this with this ajax implementation. http://jsfiddle.net/clickthelink/Uwcuz/1/

Comment: Try this. Note the method for preventing browser form submission and the manual addition of the src=ajax query parameter. http://jsfiddle.net/Uwcuz/1300/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate it. So 'src' should be accessible via $_POST, right? Can you comment on the benefits of using this over the xhr header approach? As for preventing browser default form submission, e.preventDefault(); was doing this.. See this post http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default for differences between preventDefault() and return false.

Answer (score 1):

You want to detect if this is an xhr request, and default to the non-ajax behavior if it is not.

I would look at [`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax)

Comment: Thanks @quoo. This seems very promising.. Yet there is a disclaimer on the post "$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] is the golden ticket but not all servers provide this variable so having other checks in place will be important." Care to comment? Also there were some concerns about security raised in the comments. Can this be spoofed? Also is this cross-browser compatible - atleast ie8+

Comment: I'm not quite sure what other checks he's referring to, but this article elaborates on sending the correct headers: http://heera.it/detect-ajax-request-php-frameworks#.U6L0HI1dW5I

Comment: Thanks again for the link - that clarifies things nicely. Do I add the xhr.setRequestHeader() call inside the     $("form[ajax=true]").submit(function(e) {} codeblock before the .ajax() call? (I am referring to the fiddle in my original post)

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I am accepting @mspaly response because I am a little bit concerned with Server inconsistencies with this approach. Passing an ajax parameter seems more straightforward and less risky